# Android Change Button Background Dynamically in inner class

Tags: java, android, button, background

I have the following code:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    private String packageName = MainActivity.getStringPackageName();
    private int buttonAmount = MainActivity.getButtonAmountTab1();
    private Button[] button = new Button[buttonAmount + 1];
    private Sound sound;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        sound = MainActivity.getSound();
        // Log.i("MyActivity", className);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tvtotal, container, false);

        for (int i = 1; i < buttonAmount + 1; i++) {
            String buttonID = "tv_total_sound" + i;
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", packageName);
            final int audioID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "raw", packageName);
            button[i] = (Button) rootView.findViewById(resID);
            //registerForContextMenu(button[i]);
            button[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sound.playSound(audioID);
                    button[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_active);
                }
            });
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Now instead of changing the Background of the first button (button[1]), I want to change the background of the button that is been pressed.
When I use button[i] inside the onClick ... I get an error, that i is been access from within inner class and it should be declared final. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have clicked View object from param, so:

`v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_active);`

Answer (score 0):

Use 'this' inside your onclick event:

```
This.setBackgroundResource....
```

Comment: this.setBackgroundResource ... "couldn't resolve Method"

Answer (score 0):

Button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourResource);